# Pronouncing the "N" as separate syllable at the end of words like "known" and "pattern"

Tags: pronunciation, dialects, pronunciation-vs-spelling, syllables

Over time, I have heard people pronounce the "n" on words like "known" (NO-en) and "pattern" (PAT-r-en), as though it were a separate syllable. The instances of my hearing such have been rare ones, but I can't help but think this is a remnant of some regional dialect, or perhaps due to European roots.

Where did this pronunciation originate?

Comment: The question shouldn't be *have you ever heard this?*, but *where did it come from?*  This site isn't a discussion forum (see the [FAQ](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq)).  Since I believe that's what you mean, I'll edit it accordingly, but if you had a different (but answerable, mind you) question in mind, feel free to change it.

Comment: I've never heard this before. Are these people you heard it from non-native speakers? speakers from a particular dialect? on TV? From your area? please specify.

Comment: My Saskatchewan-born grandmother said "known" that way. I've also heard *film* pronounced "fillum" (not by my grandmother, though).

Comment: I do this for many past particles: *known, grown,  drawn, hewn, sewn, blown, flown, thrown, shown* (but not *shone* or *gone*), etc. Not *pattern,* though. I'm not entirely sure where it came from, although it's likely from my mother (who grew up in central Illinois, of German descent).

Comment: I sometimes engage in this kind of hypercorrection for comic effect.

Comment: I used to work with a lot of Irish folk and they always pronounced pattern as "pattren". I've never heard anyone else use it that way.

Comment: It's common in Yugoslav countries.

Comment: I'm Irish and I say "patt-er-en" and "fill-em".

Comment: That extra schwa is very common in New Zealand English http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Zealand_English

Comment: The technical term for slipping an extra vowel (usually a shwa in English) before a final resonant, or anywhere else in a word, is [**Epenthesis** /ɛ'pɛnθəsɪs/](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epenthesis), and the extra vowel is called an **Epenthetic** /ɛpən'θɛtɪk/ vowel. The automnemonic for _Epenthesis_ is _Epenethesis_ /ɛpən'ɛθəsɪs/.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be two separate phenomena, with different origins.

From the other answers, in some Irish dialects, words ending in consonant clusters such as *-rn* and *-lm* have the *n* and *m* pronounced as a separate syllable. This may be a hold-over from earlier English pronunciation. Apparently Shakespeare sometimes spelled *"film"* as *phillum*, so it appears he pronounced *film* this way. See the comments for [this Language Log post](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=6892). (Although it's possible both the one- and two-syllable pronunciations were used in Shakespeare's time, and he chose the two-syllable one for the sake of the meter).

The other phenomenon is restricted to past participles.  I do it for past participles such as *known, grown, thrown, mown, hewn, strewn* (so *mown* is pronounced as in *Moe 'n Larry*).  This is pure speculation on my part, but it's possible that this originated with German immigrants—in German, irregular verbs all have past participles that either end with 't' or 'en'  (except for *tun*, with past participle *getan*). So for a German learning English, it would be natural to pronounce these past participles as if they ended with *en.*

Comment: It doesn’t necessarily have to come from German—the normal passive participle marker for strong verbs in English is also _-en_ whenever an unacceptable final cluster would otherwise arise, i.e., everywhere except after vowels (including diphthongs) and r. There was originally an e there, but it’s been syncopated away where possible. There could be dialects that did not take part in this syncope, or (more likely, I think) certain dialects could have reintroduced it analogically.

Answer (score 2):

I was brought up in North Essex (proper Essex, not that stuff near London they make jokes about). We always pronounced know-en as two syllables. The same goes for similar words. I still pronounce it that way, even though others look at me strangely. I think it goes back to the East Saxon dialect. I'm patriotic!

Comment: Same here. Born and bred Londoner here. I always pronounce grown as 2 syllables. For me, it is *not* a homophone of “groan”. Same with thrown, shown, known etc. All 2 syllables.

Answer (score 0):

I'm hearing "NO-un" working with Chicagoans who lean more to the Wisconsin accent.

Answer (score 0):

I used to hear it in Michigan but only from people born before 1970 (I guess).  Now living in Seattle, same thing.  I noticed recently that Norm Macdonald does this, too.

Comment: Hi Carole. People in most of the English-speaking world are unlikely to know who Norm Macdonald is. Please explain, and preferably add a link to provide evidence. Note that this site is a bit different from other Q&A sites: an answer is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. You can add extra detail by using the [edit] link; for further guidance, see [Answer]. I can also recommend taking the **[Tour]**. :-)

Answer (score -3):

Usually these types of words come from ancient times (Middle English, Anglo-Saxon, Gaelic). So for a word like *known* that comes from *knowen* (pronounced something like NOu-En), some people tend to do the emphasis as it would in former times.

I have also seen this type of behavior in foreign speakers… like myself.

Comment: There were many more forms than just *knownen* in Middle English. Why would this be the one that got kept? It seems a little too "just so" for my liking.